# Sum over divisors of sum over coprimes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Set $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , $n>1$ . Consider the function $\phi_{1}$ as

$$\phi_{1}(n)= \sum _{r=1 \atop \gcd(r,n) =1}^{n} r$$

Prove that

$$\sum_{d|n} d \cdot \phi_{1}\Big(\frac{n}{d}\Big) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k$$

Do you have any hint or advice for this? I´ve tried everything but i get to nowhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be proved that for $n>1$ $$\phi_1(n)=\Big(\frac{n \cdot\phi(n)}{2}\Big)$$

This is because, if $k$ is a co-prime, then $n-k$ is also co-prime. Adding these gives $n$. There are a total of $\phi(n)/2$ such pairs and hence the sum.

As for $n=1$, its $1$.

Now, $$\sum_{d|n} d \cdot \phi_{1}\Big(\frac{n}{d}\Big) = \sum_{d\lt n,d|n} d \cdot \frac{n}{2d}\cdot\phi\Big(\frac{n}{d}\Big) = 
\sum_{d\lt n,d|n}\frac{n}{2}\cdot\phi\Big(\frac{n}{d}\Big) = \frac{n}{2}\cdot\sum_{d\lt n,d|n} \phi\Big(\frac{n}{d}\Big)$$

But, $$\sum_{d|n} \phi\Big(\frac{n}{d}\Big) = n$$
See [this](http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/NumberTh04Totient.aspx) for proof. Since $d<n$ the sum is actually $n-1$.
We also need to take into account when $d=n$ which gives $n$.

Combining everything, we get:
$$\frac{n}{2} \cdot(n-1) + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

which is the required result.

Comment: Understood but i still don't get why $\phi_{1}(n) = \Big(\frac{n \cdot \phi(n)}{2}\Big)$

Comment: You need to count all the co-primes. If $k$ is a co-prime, $n-k$ is also a co-prime.Adding these two gives $n$. There are a total of $\phi(n)$ co-primes, which means $\phi(n)/2$ pairs. Each pair gives a sum of $n$. Hence, $\frac{n.\phi(n)}{2}$ will be the total sum.